# Google Cal API - Script to Check Events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to build a script that will check a Authenticated User's Google Calendar via the Google Calendar PHP Client. I was able to build a simple page that lets a user Auth and give permission to the Calendar Events. I receive a token and then grab a 15 upcoming events via:

```
$googleCal = new Google_Service_Calendar($googleClient);
$results = $googleCal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

But what I'm struggling with is how to save this so I can have a script check this everyday to see if there were new events added. I think what I have is close just struggling to get over the finish line.

Thanks!

--

Update, I'm trying to use the refresh token, here is my code:

```
public function checkRedirectCode()
  {
        if(isset($_GET['code']))
        {
              $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

        //    $this->setToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
              $this->setToken($this->client->getAccessToken());

              $this->storeUser($this->getPayload());

              return true;
        }

        return false;
  }

  public function setToken($token)
  {
              $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
              $this->client->setAccessToken($token);

  }
```

I have been able to echo the refresh token so I know I'm getting a proper refresh token but I'm getting errors whenever I use the commented out string. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use 'getEventsForDay(date)'? this will give you all events that occurs on a given day. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEventsForDay(Date)

Comment: The token you get back is only valid for an hour, so make sure you use the refresh token instead, else you won't be able to run the script everyday. Let me know if you want me to share how to do this, apologies if you're already doing it.

Comment: @jksn.co I would love an example if you have one!

Comment: @ChrisOlson Think about this working in two parts. 1) Your original script works fine, you just need to save the refresh token to a database, you don't need to use the refresh token at this point. 2) Build a script that will run daily (on a cron) that uses the refresh token (like in my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

To enable your script to be called beyond the lifetime of the original access token (which only last an hour), you will need to retrieve and store the refresh token during the initial authorisation, and then use this to generate a new access token each time your script runs.

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access
>   to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can
>   obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to
>   obtain new access tokens.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps (4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.)

After the user has authenticated your app, they are returned to your redirect URI with the `code` query-string.

The following is an example of authenticating and getting the refresh token (this uses Analytics, but should be the same for other services):

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('xxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxx');

//authenticate with the code returned from google
$authenticate = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

//get the refresh token
$refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();

//store refresh token in database...
```

Then, when you run your daily script, use the refresh token (retrieved from your database) to generate a new access token:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('xxx');
$client->setClientSecret('yyy');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

$client->refreshToken($user->refresh_token);
$newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($newToken);
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the update I made in the initial post? I've been trying to use my refresh code, which I'm properly getting (you can see the commented out line) but it's not working. Thoughts?

Comment: When refreshing the token, does the scope need to be set? Or can a new access_token be retrieved without any explicit scope?